# Can we convert the Existing HNSC to New separate web application?

Tags: 2013, web-application, hnsc

We have one HNSC created in our  SP2013 farm.Now we have a requirement to create separate web application created instead of this existing HNSC.
Is there any step by step guide to convert the Existing HNSC to New separate web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can move a a Host Name Site Collection (HNSC) from one web application to another via `Backup-SPSite` and `Restore-SPSite` as the following:

- Take a backup of your site collection via PowerShell `Backup-SPSite -Identity <SiteCollectionGUIDorURL> -Path <BackupFile>`
- Crate a new web application,
- Restore your site collection to the new web application. `Restore-SPSite -Identity <SiteCollectionGUIDorURL> -Path <BackupFile>`
- Remove site collection from old web application based on your requirements.`Remove-SPSite -Identity < Old SiteCollectionGUIDorURL> -Confirm:$false`
- Delete backup file.`Remove-Item "<BackupFile>"`

For more details check

- [Back up site collections in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748617.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Restore site collections in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748655.aspx)
- [MOVE A SITE COLLECTION FROM ONE WEB APPLICATION TO ANOTHER](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/10/28/how-to-move-site-collection-from-one-webapplication/)